# Example of a Borel set that is neither $F_\sigma$ nor $G_\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I'm looking for subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ such that $A$ is a Borel set but $A$ is neither $F_\sigma$ nor $G_\delta$.

Comment: For references to the related problem of "explicit" examples of functions that properly belong to various lower Baire hierarchy ranks, see http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/addcfd658075c65f

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are many examples. Here's one:

Observe first that the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ are an $F_{\sigma}$. This is because they are a countable union of points. The irrational numbers $\mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \mathbb{Q} = \bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \{q\}$ are thus a $G_{\delta}$. Since both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \mathbb{Q}$ are dense and disjoint it follows from the [Baire category theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) that $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be a $G_{\delta}$. [**Edit:** See also [this thread here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69451/how-to-show-that-mathbbq-is-not-g-delta) containing several proofs that $\mathbb{Q}$ can't be a $G_{\delta}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. These proofs explicitly avoid Baire].

The same reasoning shows that $F = \mathbb{Q}_{\geq 0}$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ in $[0,\infty)$, but isn't a $G_{\delta}$, and that $G= \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0} \smallsetminus \mathbb{Q}_{\leq 0}$ is a $G_{\delta}$ in $(-\infty,0]$, but isn't an $F_{\sigma}$. Their union $F \cup G$ is then an example of a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is neither an $F_{\sigma}$ nor a $G_{\delta}$ because if it were an $F_{\sigma}$ then the same would hold for $G = (F \cup G) \cap (-\infty,0)$, for example. I leave it as an exercise to show that $F \cup G$ is both an $F_{\sigma\delta}$ and a $G_{\delta\sigma}$.

That's probably the easiest example. A few more (both more interesting but also more involved ones) can be found in [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56632/).

---

For a much more in-depth discussion of such ideas, I recommend looking into one of the following books:

- A.S. Kechris, *[Classical Descriptive Set Theory](http://books.google.com/books/about/Classical_descriptive_set_theory.html?id=pPv9KCEkklsC)*, Springer GTM 156.
- S.M. Srivastava, *[A course on Borel sets](http://books.google.com/books?id=FhYGYJtMwcUC)*, Springer GTM 180.
- J.C. Oxtoby, *[Measure and Category](http://books.google.com/books?id=wUDjoT5xIFAC)*, Springer GTM 2.

Specifically, look up the sections on the [Borel hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy).

Comment: Very nice example! I had in mind some countable union of copies of the irrationals or something like that.