# Example that is neither an Fσ nor a Gδ but it is an Fσδ.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, intuition

I can not find any example which can satisfy the given situation.

If there is any example then please explain that to me.

A subset of R that is neither an Fσ nor a Gδ but it is an Fσδ.

Also if anybody can explain diagram of fig 1.1.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB8vy.png)

Comment: A simple counterexample is provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73296/example-of-a-borel-set-that-is-neither-f-sigma-nor-g-delta?rq=1)

Comment: But also prove that this example belongs to  Fσδ.

Answer (score 1):

For a trivial and uninteresting example, let $A\subset(0,1)$ be an $F_\sigma$ but not a $G_\delta,$ and let $B\subset(2,3)$ be a $G_\delta$ but not an $F_\sigma;$ then $S=A\cup B$ will be an $F_{\sigma\delta}$ and a $G_{\delta\sigma}$ but neither a $G_\delta$ nor an $F_\sigma.$ For instance, $S=((0,1)\cap\mathbb Q)\cup((2,3)\setminus\mathbb Q).$