# Countable intersection of F-sigma sets and G-delta sets

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

1) For me it is clear that a countable union of $F_\sigma$  sets is $F_\sigma$, but how to prove that countable INTERSECTION of $F_{\sigma}$ sets is $F_{\sigma}$ set ?
2) Prove that countable intersection of $G_{\delta}$ sets is $G_{\delta}$ set.

I tried to show (2):
$$l \in \mathbb{N}, A_{l}\textit{ is } G_{\delta}, A_{l}=\bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}V_{n}^{l}$$
$$\bigcap\limits_{l \in \mathbb{N}}A_{l}= \bigcap\limits_{l \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}V_{n}^{l} = \bigcap\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}}W_{i}$$  $$ x \in \bigcap\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}}W_{i}\Leftrightarrow \forall i\in \mathbb{N} \ x \in V_{n}^{l}\Leftrightarrow x \in \bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcap\limits_{l \in \mathbb{N}}V_{n}^{l}  
$$

Comment: Please, don't add questions after you've been answered. It makes existing answers look silly.

Comment: A countable intersection of $F_\sigma$ sets is called an $F_{\sigma\delta}$ set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Claim (1) is not true.

$\Bbb R^n$ is a second-countable metric space, therefore open sets are $F_\sigma$. Your claim specialized to this case would then imply that all $G_\delta$ sets of $\Bbb R^n$ are $F_\sigma$. And, therefore, that $F_\sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R^n$. Specifically, $F_\sigma=G_\delta=\text{Borel}$. [But this is not the case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73296/example-of-a-borel-set-that-is-neither-f-sigma-nor-g-delta).

For (2) you can use the lemma for countable union of $F_\sigma$ and the fact that a set is $G_\delta$ if and only if it is the complement of a $F_\sigma$.

Comment: Open sets are $F_{\sigma}$ in any metric space....The Baire Category Theorem implies that a dense $G_{\delta}$ subset of $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, so $ \Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb Q$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set which is not $F_{\sigma}.$...................+1

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Ah, true. I could have used the distance from the complement.