# Borel sigma algebra is formed by countable union/intersection/complements of open sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space. The claim is that $E\in\mathscr{B}(X):=\sigma(T)$ if and only if $E$ can be obtained by countable union/intersection/complement of open sets in $X$.

For the reverse direction, if $E$ is a countable union/intersection/complement of open sets in $X$, then $E\in S_\alpha$ for each $\sigma$-algebra $S_\alpha$ such that $T\subseteq S_\alpha$, so $E\in\mathscr{B}(X)$.

But I'm not sure how to prove the other direction.
If $E\in\mathscr{B}(X)$, then $E\in S_\alpha$ for every $\sigma$-algebra $S_\alpha$ such that $T\subseteq S_\alpha$. Why should $E$ be a countable union/intersection/complement of open sets?

Comment: It isn't. Not every Borel set is the  countable union, etc. of open sets. It's defined as the smallest collection of sets containing the open sets which is closed under these operations.

Comment: @Chris Can you give an example of a Borel set that is not a countable union/intersection/complement of open sets, say in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73296/example-of-a-borel-set-that-is-neither-f-sigma-nor-g-delta

Answer (score 0):

The set of all rational numbers is not a countable union/intersection of complement of open sets. The fact that it is not  a countable intersection of open sets is not elementary, but it is a standard application of Baire Category Theorem. Of course this set is a Borel set because it is a countable union of singleton sets.