# Lebesgue Measurable Set which is not a union of a Borel set and a subset of a null $F_\sigma$ set?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

The Lebesgue Sigma algebra is the completion of the Borel Sigma algebra under the Lebesgue measure, which means that every Lebesgue measurable set can be written as a union of a Borel set and a subset of a measure $0$ Borel set.  But my question is, what is an example of a Lebesgue measurable set which cannot be written as a union of a Borel set and a subset of a measure $0$ $F_\sigma$ set?

Or does no such example exist?

Comment: May be; take a a union of a Borel set and a subset of a measure 0 $G_\delta$ set ??

Comment: @Bumblebee You can't just choose any union of a Borel set and a subset of a measure $0$ $G_\delta$ set, because it's possible that that set can also be written as a union of a Borel set and a subset of a measure $0$ $F_\sigma$ set.

Comment: Oh, I see. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73296/example-of-a-borel-set-that-is-neither-f-sigma-nor-g-delta) might be helpful.

Comment: @Bumblebee It's easy to find an example of a Borel set that is neither $F_\sigma$ nor $G_\delta$, but how would that help us?  Regardless of what Borel set of measure $0$ you take, the union of a given subset of it with a Borel set might still be able to be written as a union of a Borel set and a subset of a measure 0 $F_\sigma$ set.

Comment: Why can every Lebesgue measurable set be written as a union of a Borel set and a subset of a measure $0$ Borel set? I only know we can write a Lebesgue measurable set as a union of a Borel set and a Lebesgue measure $0$ set.

Comment: @Bach Every Lebesgue measurable measure zero set is a subset of a measure 0 Borel set.  In any case, the fact that every Lebesgue measurable set can be written as a union of a Borel set and a subset of a measure 0 Borel set is a standard result, usually stated as “the Lebesgue sigma algebra is the completion of the Borel algebra”.  A more general result which implies this result is proven in Theorem 1.6.6 in this chapter of Junghenn’s Measure Theory book: https://gdurl.com/dw43 If it’s too difficult to understand I can find a simpler proof for you.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan That's very helpful. Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an example in [this journal paper](http://gdurl.com/xU6F).  Let $\beta$ be a Bernstein set, i.e. a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that both it and its complement intersects every uncountable closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  ([This post](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/bernstein-set/) describes how to construct such a set using the axiom of choice.)  And let $\gamma$ be a dense measure-$0$ $G_\delta$ subset of the [fat Cantor set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set).  ([This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2993362/71829) describes how to construct such a set.)

Then $\beta\cap\gamma$ is a Lebesgue measurable set which cannot be written as a union of a Borel set and a subset of a measure $0$ $F_\sigma$ set.  This is proven in the linked paper.