# Example of non G-delta set

Tags: real-analysis

An open set is clearly a $G_{\delta}$ set. A closed interval $[a,b]$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set as an intersection of the open intervals $(a-\frac1n,b+\frac1n)$ for all positive integers $n$. What is an example of a set that's not $G_{\delta}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $\Bbb Q$ of rational numbers is not a $G_\delta$ set; you can find several proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69451/how-to-show-that-mathbbq-is-not-g-delta).

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown using something called the Baire Category Theorem that the set of all rational numbers is not a $G_{\delta}$ set.