# Does exist a continuous real valued function on the rational number but discontinuous on the irracional numbers?

Tags: calculus

There is a famous example of a function continuous on irrational numbers but discontinuous on the rational numbers. My question  is the converse of this example. 
Thanks!

Comment: no.  Here is an explanation why https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function#Follow-up

Comment: Great! . Thanks.

Comment: The set of continuity points of a real function must be a $G_\delta$ set, but the rationals aren't $G_\delta$.

Comment: And here are proofs that $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't $G_\delta$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69451/how-to-show-that-mathbbq-is-not-g-delta